# forloop increment not understanding

Tags: java, for-loop

```
for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
{
    for(int j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++)
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

The value of `i` after the first loop should be still `0`, but it is incremented to `1`.
This is where I am not clear on the code. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: "The value of i after first loop should be still 0" Why do you think so?

Comment: check your condition in the second loop. there's no first iteration in second loop at all..

Comment: Yes because i put the print statement before j loop then I got the value 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Iteration

```
for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)  i = 0,true,
{
for(int j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++)    j=1 , j<=-1 which is false . so it is skipping 
    System.out.println(i);  prints nothing 
}
```

second Iteration

```
for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)  i = 1,true,
{
for(int j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++)    j=1 , j<=1 which is true. so now it runs loop inside 
    System.out.println(i); so now prints 1
}
```

If you are a beginnerto loops. Always draw [trace table dry runs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Data_Representation_and_Practical_Exercise/Problem_Solving/Trace_tables)

Comment: Yes I got it now Thanks.

Comment: Yes i am newly learning programming, Thanks for ur trace method I will use it

Answer (score 2):

When `i` is `0` the inner loop (the one based on `j`'s value) doesn't run. The condition evaluates to `j<=-1`, so the loop is never entered, and the `System.out.println` statement is never executed. Only on the second loop, when `i` is `1` the second loop has a chance to execute.

Answer (score 1):

In the inner loop the condition "for(int j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++)" needs to be satisfied, in case of i=0 , this loop will not execute in the first iteration, hence it will go to second iteration i.e. i=1.